# UICollectionViewCell reuse doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have cell of different width and horisontal UICollectionView, but often 
when I dequeue cell:

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
```

it uses the same cell with the same object address.

**Update:**

I mean that UICollectionView uses the same cell for all IndexPath . In debug I see the address of the cell and it's the same all the time. But I think that it's the way, UICollectionView implemented, the bug was in another point, but anyway it's strange

Comment: T can you please explain this in more detail-: for 2 index pathes that are on the screen, it uses the same cell, so that the data displayed for the 1st cell is incorrect.

Comment: @TusharSharma , I added an update

Answer (score 0):

Reusable cells come into picture when there are more cells than to fit the screen. You just have 2 fresh objects of cells with 2 `indexPath` rows that are visible on the screen.

Try checking the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` wherein you configure or modify the cell's data after you instantiate them, you would have given same data to show in both cells or you wouldn't have changed the default values for the cell's view's UI elements which my cause the data to repeat.